# How to compare array of objects and replace unmatched value with original value JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.I want to compare only quantity in both array. 
In second array i want to replace the unmatched values from first array. 
Like 50 Qty is not in second array so i want to replace this from first array

```
' Array1 = [{
  'Sk': 6,
  'Qty': 50
},
{
  'SK': 5,
  'Qty': 20
},
{
  'SK': 5,
  'Qty': 20
}
Array2 = [{
  'Sk': 6,
  'Qty': 80
},
{
  'SK': 5,
  'Qty': 20
},
{
  'SK': 5,
  'Qty': 20
}
```

`
How to do that please let me know?

Comment: It sounds like you're overcomplicating it. Just don't write the new value to session storage unless the user clicks "Ok"...

Comment: This is requirement to fulfill other condition so i have to use it

Answer (score 0):

Still not entirely sure of what you're trying to do, but here's how I'd structure it:

```
function onUserCancel() {
  if (Array2[i] !== Array1[i]) { // where i is the index of the changed element
    Array2[i] = Array1[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(arr1, arr2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i].Qty !== arr2[i].Qty) {
      arr2[i].Qty = arr1[i].Qty
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But i want to compare only qty in both arrays